Linear Frequency Modulated signal instantaneous power
I am currently working with FMCW Radar, where the frequency $f(t)$ of the transmit signal $s_{tx}(t)$ is swept over a certain bandwidth $B$ with a rate $\mu = \frac{B}{T_c}$.
Generally, such a chirp can be described as:
$$
s_{tx}(t) = e^{2j\pi(ft + \frac{\mu}{2}t^2)}
$$
giving the instantaneous frequency as:
$$
f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{d\phi(t)}{dt} = f + \frac{\mu}{2}t
$$
What is the correct way to access how much such a signal used in a radar would interfere with other signals, e.g. Wifi, Bluetooth, 433MHz, etc? By that I mean more the interference caused to those other services instead of interference caused by the services to the FMCW radar.
Since the instantaneous frequency is just a singular frequency for a very short time, would I do something like a short time fourier transform and look at the instantaneous power to estimate this? Are there typically regulations to look out for, like how much power is allowed for how long on a certain band used by another service? Or is it generally 100% forbidden to emit signals on those bands?
Some keywords to look for would be much appreciated!

Keep in mind that since you're doing FMCW, you're going to be emitting a band of frequencies around the carrier, so you need to consider those and not just the single carrier frequency.

The instantaneous frequency you stated is incorrect it is $ f +\mu t$. For high time bandwidth products the Fourier transform has a good approximation. As you go to lower time bandwidth products the spectrum spreads out more. Pretty much all regulations I've seen (US and Canada) refer to average power - instantaneous power is not a good metric. See Dan's answer for more info.

Regulatory requirements are clear in specifying a mask as the limit of power in adjacent channels and how this power is measured. Notably the resolution bandwidth of the measuring equipment is specified. Resolution bandwidth is essentially the reciprocal of observation time (it is mathematically related to how long the spectrum is observed and essentially averaged). Because of that, there is no measurement of instantaneous power or frequency, only average. So knowing that, you would observe the spectrum with that resolution bandwidth while your transmitter is operating (and modulating) and confirm that you are not violating any emission limits.
See this for example: https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/22.359#:~:text=(a)%20Out%20of%20band%20emissions,10%20log%20(P)%20dB.
